# Safe and cheap way to decompress gas

Tags: pressure, temperature, education

I'm looking for a cheap and safe way to demonstrate how releasing pressurised gas from a container can take the container from room temperature to freezing (cold enough for ice to form on the container itself) in a classroom environment. I basically have two ideas:

1. Diving flask. This is relatively safe because there is just air inside, so there are no dangerous substances involved. The price of renting one is also not too high, and I do have a licence, so there won't be any bureaucratic problems involving the excuse "but I'm not going to be using it for diving". However, it is heavy, it needs to be rented and transported, and I don't actually know that it's going to become cold enough. I never tried releasing that much that fast. Releasing air directly from the flask is also quite noisy.
2. Compressed air for electronic cleaning. This is easier to get a hold of, and easier to transport, although the price is about the same. In this case I know that it will become cold enough. However, it's usually not really air inside it, which will mandate a well ventilated environment. It's also smaller, so it's more difficult to get away with me demonstrating it alone as opposed to everyone getting their own to try it out (or, at least in groups), which again makes me worried about ventilation (and also costs)

Are there any other obvious instances of compressed gas that would work that I've missed? Have you done this activity (either as teacher or as student), and want to share what worked for you?

Comment: Have a look at this YouTube video https://youtu.be/6S88XeA6fbM

Comment: @Farcher Pressure cooker. That's easy and cool and safe and cheap. Needs some warmup time, but that's not a big problem.

Answer (score 1):

CO2 fire extinguisher.

1, You don't have to rent or carry one. There is probably one within reach.

2, They get very cold.

3, You can claim you are doing a safety demonstration

Comment: Let's just hope it's not foam or powder.

Comment: @Arthur then you also learn the important experimental physics lesson of reading the label before releasing the contents

Comment: Both this and compressed "air" (actually, it's HFCs) for cleaning electronics have the problem that they are actually both decompressing gas and boiling liquid.